# Вывести значения из ключей в объекте в html

Tags: javascript, циклы, объекты, dom

В html страницу выводит дублированное значение, но в html всего 1 блок

```
    title:  {
        name: 'some text here', 
        desc: 'some text here'
    },
    title2: {
        name: 'some text here',
        desc: 'some text here',
    },
    title3: {
        name: 'some text here',
        desc: 'some text here',
    },
    title4: {
        name: 'some text here',
        desc: 'some text here',
    },
    title5: {
        name: 'some text here', 
        desc: 'some text here',
    },
    title6: {
        name: 'some text here', 
        desc: 'some text here',
    },
    title7: {
        name: 'some text here', 
        desc: 'some text here---'
    }
}
for (const key in users) {
    for (const keyN in users[key]) {
        parag.innerHTML += users[key].name + '<br>'
    }
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно

Comment: Вопрос весьма понятен! Вывести на страницу html ЗНАЧЕНИЯ КЛЮЧЕЙ ОБЪЕКТА. Все максимально разжеванно

Comment: "В html страницу выводит дублированное значение, но в html всего 1 блок" --- если ты считаешь это максимально разжёванным, то у меня для тебя плохие новости........это ломаннный эльфийский

Comment: Нужно что-то - допустим, а проблема-то в чём? Всё также не ясно

Answer (score 0):

Вложенный цикл `for...in` тут ни к чему, уберите его.

```js
const users = {
  title: {
    name: 'some text here',
    desc: 'some text here'
  },
  title2: {
    name: 'some text here',
    desc: 'some text here',
  },
  title3: {
    name: 'some text here',
    desc: 'some text here',
  },
  title4: {
    name: 'some text here',
    desc: 'some text here',
  },
  title5: {
    name: 'some text here',
    desc: 'some text here',
  },
  title6: {
    name: 'some text here',
    desc: 'some text here',
  },
  title7: {
    name: 'some text here',
    desc: 'some text here---'
  }
}
for (const key in users) {
  // for (const keyN in users[key]) {
  document.body.innerHTML += users[key].name + '<br>'
  // }
}
```